# why android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE register in manifest don't work at first time?

Tags: android, broadcast

I want to listen network status,i use broadcast and register in Androidmanifest.xml。but i can't receive broadcast after my app start. i test in samsung s3 and nexus 5 and xiaomi，that also happen.i know register in manifest is a static mode,if i register in app code(Dynamic mode) that's will ok,who can tell why,is android bug?

```
<receiver android:name="com.l555iu.receiver.MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you add the permision ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE?

add this one on your manifest

This is working perfectly on my nexus 5

Comment: yes,I do.but when first time,it doesn't ok.I expect when i start app the network broadcast should triggered